# If $ s_{n} $ is a complex sequence with $| s_{n} |>0$ can we say that $ s_{n} >0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm new to complex sequences. I'm trying to proof a property for a complex sequence and I'm stuck at this inequality. If $| s_{n} |>0$ can I say that $ s_{n} >0$?

Comment: Complex number aren't an ordered field, so comparing $s$ to $0$ is meaningless.

Comment: No. That's not even true if you know $s_n$ is real. For example, what happens if $s_n=-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; complex numbers do not have an ordering. As an example, think if $i>0$, then $-1=i\cdot i>0$, which is obviously false, and conversely, if $i<0$, then $1=(-i)\cdot i<0$, which again is false.

Comment: To be more precise, there's no order structure on $\mathbb C$ which is compatible with the field structure.

Comment: Thanks for he explanation :)